# Is there any way to get a list of columns from a response to a ADO Command query?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, ado

I am trying to get a list of Active Directory (AD) users (and related information) using VBscript.
The problem is that I do not know how to get full list of received columns.

I've tried to look (by using debugger of Visual Studio 2017) what is inside of response (object "objUser"), but debugger showed only dots.

Main set:

```
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

strQuery = "<LDAP://" + strDNSDomain + ">;(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectSid=*)(!samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=3)));objectGUID;subtree"
objCommand.CommandText = strQuery

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

processed in loop

```
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    strLine = ""

    arrbytGuid = objRecordSet.Fields("objectGUID")
    strDN = "<GUID=" + OctetToHexStr(arrbytGuid) + ">"
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)

    If (Not IsNull(objUser.SAMAccountName)) Then
        strLine = CStr(objUser.SAMAccountName)
    End If

    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

I want to understand what other columns there are in "objUser" besides "SAMAccountName".

Comment: Look at the `objRecordSet.Fields` collection, use a `For` loop to go through and return the field names.

Comment: The only item of `objRecordSet.Fields` collection is `objectGUID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note you are making an extra network request where you don't need to. I'll discuss the search first.

All the field names that you get back in the search are in `objRecordSet.Fields`. You only see `objectGUID` because that's all you asked for.

The `;objectGUID;` in your query is where you list (comma-separated) the attributes you want returned.

The extra network request happens after this:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)
```

You are binding to the object directly, just for the purpose of reading attributes. More specifically, once you access a property (`objUser.SAMAccountName`) it goes out to AD and loads the attributes. And the same principal applies here: if you don't specifically tell it which attributes you are going to want, it will load every attribute with a value. This will slow down your loop and you don't need to do it, since you can read everything you need to read from your search.

Instead, get the search to return everything you need. If you need `sAMAccountName` too, add it: `;objectGUID,sAMAccountName;`.

The only reason to bind directly to an object after a search is if you need to update it.

---

But to specifically answer the question you asked, this is how you can see which attributes an object has after binding directly to it using `GetObject()`:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)
objUser.GetInfo() 'Retrieve all attributes with a value

For I = 0 To objUser.PropertyCount - 1
   Set pEntry = objUser.Item(I)
   Wscript.Echo pEntry.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I tried both of options: when I changed `;objectGUID;` to `;;` in `strQuery` I got an error :( ; when I tried to see attributes I got the list and noticed strange thing - the list did not contain some attributes I requested earlier, `Department`, for example.

Comment: What does the error say? Also, it will only return attributes with values. Does `department` have a value for the object you're looking at?

Comment: I'm trying it out myself. Apparently using `;;` doesn't work. I'll see if I can figure it out. It's been a while since I've used VBScript for this. In every other language you just don't tell it which attributes you want and it'll return everything. Ideally, you should tell it which attributes you want anyway since it'll always be faster.

Comment: The error `80040E14` with text `One or more errors occurred during processing of command.` is occuring on line `Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute`. I think, you are right and the _first_ object in list I test with my code probably doesn't have a `department`. I can later check each attribute for each object and collect full list of attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find a way to retrieve all attributes in VBScript. Weird. You can do it everywhere else: PowerShell, .NET, etc. I removed that part of my answer.